# converting US tickers into Reuters RIC

Tags: equities, bloomberg, reuters

I have a large list of US equity tickers such as:
"GIRO", "ITUB", "BITA" etc

and I would like to convert them into their corresponding RIC codes. Do you know how can I do it? I have access to Bloomberg and to Thomson EIKON...

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your request is too broad. ITUB, for example is an Italian company and has ADRs traded in several stock exchanges. Hence, if you do search in Eikon, you find multiple tickers for it.

And I failed to find critea, which could yield single return value for each tickers you supplied.

I used request: =RSearch("Equity", "TickerSymbol:" & B3 & "*") where you place your ticker into B3 cell.

For GIRO there are:
GIRO.PA
GIRO.PA1
GIROp.TQ
GIROp.BS
GIROp.CHI

For BITA I had:
BITA.K
BITA.N
BITA.TH
BITA.P
BITA.DG
BITA.Z
BITA.B
BITA.C
BITA.W
BITA.DY
BITA.ZY
BITA.PH
BITA.MW
BITA.DF
BITA.ITC
BITA.NB

And there were ever more tickers for ITUB.
When I added search criteria, number of results decreased.

I have no Bloomberg, but when I used http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/ I had similar results:

Symbol: ITUB

Market Sector: Equity

Security Type: ADR, Common Stock

And there were 14 BBGIDs.

Hence, I think there's no direct way to do it.

Comment: thank you very much rustam for your nice answer. actually what is just want to do is to merge a file which contains equity tickers with a file which contains RIC codes. for the examples you provided, I have the feeling that the RIC code is merely the ticker + some ".whatsoever" stuff. In that case I would merge just on the basis of the ticker. What do you think? Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like that's the case. Unfortunately, I can't say for sure, but I'd suggest you to try.